# How to pick a file I/O buffer size for reading a file in Windows?

Tags: networking, file-io, buffer, windows-explorer, wan

While investigating some slow performance in my application while reading a file over a WAN, I noticed that copying that file in Windows Explorer was significantly faster.

Some further investigation with Process Monitor revealed the cause: my application was using the C runtime's default BUFSIZE of 512, while Windows Explorer had somehow determined that it should read the file in 61440 byte blocks (which is apparently the maximum supported by either SMB or Windows' implementation of SMB).  As a result, Windows Explorer had to make a LOT fewer round trips and ran a lot faster.

Most recommendations for buffer size are somewhere in the 4k-16k range, but for a WAN environment, minimizing round trips by maximizing the buffer size makes sense.  How does Windows Explorer determine what buffer size to use?

Comment: Does it always use 61440? Or does it use different amounts? Maybe it was hard-coded..

Comment: does it use the same read size for (non network copy)?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that something less than the network MTU might be good

Comment: SMB might have optimizations at the network level to stay below the MTU, but at the system call level (ReadFile), Process Monitor shows that Explorer uses 61440.

Comment: Something several times the size of the MTU would be a lot better :-)